# Trying to add total for individual for every month/year

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, ssms

"   We have two tables. One for hours which have been sent to a vendor (Master) and one for the hours we are about to send (Load). I am attempting to sum the hours based on month and year for each individual with subtotals. We want to find those individuals who have more than 300 hours for a particular month.

```
 CREATE TABLE MasterTabletesting(
     ID          CHAR(9) NOT NULL 
    ,Workdate    DATE  NOT NULL
    ,Emp         CHAR(30) NOT NULL
    ,HoursWorked DECIMAL(18,2) NOT NULL);
  INSERT INTO  MasterTabletesting(ID,Workdate,Emp,HoursWorked) VALUES ('25','20160731','7502',24);
  INSERT INTO  MasterTabletesting(ID,Workdate,Emp,HoursWorked) VALUES ('25','20160731','21874',128);
  INSERT INTO  MasterTabletesting(ID,Workdate,Emp,HoursWorked) VALUES ('25','20160731','7502',166);
  INSERT INTO  MasterTabletesting(ID,Workdate,Emp,HoursWorked) VALUES ('72','20160831','7508',180);
  INSERT INTO  MasterTabletesting(ID,Workdate,Emp,HoursWorked) VALUES ('72','20160831','5501',180);
  INSERT INTO  MasterTabletesting(ID,Workdate,Emp,HoursWorked) VALUES ('72','20160831','21037',23);
  INSERT INTO  MasterTabletesting(ID,Workdate,Emp,HoursWorked) VALUES ('66','20160831','83641',22);



  CREATE TABLE LoadTabletesting(
     ID          CHAR(9) NOT NULL 
    ,Workdate    CHAR(8)  NOT NULL
    ,Emp         CHAR(30) NOT NULL
    ,HoursWorked DECIMAL(18,2) NOT NULL);
  INSERT INTO  LoadTabletesting(ID,Workdate,Emp,HoursWorked) VALUES ('8','07312016','7500',24);
  INSERT INTO  LoadTabletesting(ID,Workdate,Emp,HoursWorked) VALUES ('6','07312016','21974',128);
  INSERT INTO  LoadTabletesting(ID,Workdate,Emp,HoursWorked) VALUES ('25','07312016','7500',166);
  INSERT INTO  LoadTabletesting(ID,Workdate,Emp,HoursWorked) VALUES ('72','08312016','7500',180);
  INSERT INTO  LoadTabletesting(ID,Workdate,Emp,HoursWorked) VALUES ('88','08312016','5507',180);
  INSERT INTO  LoadTabletesting(ID,Workdate,Emp,HoursWorked) VALUES ('23','08312016','21012',23);
  INSERT INTO  LoadTabletesting(ID,Workdate,Emp,HoursWorked) VALUES ('55','08312016','83667',22);}
```

The date in the load table is a char variable type which I have resolved with cast. My approach has been to place the necessary data from both tables in a view titled "Over300agtest:

```
SELECT ID AS 'ID'
,Employer AS 'Emp'
,month(WorkDate) AS 'Mnth'
,year(WorkDate) AS 'Yr'
,HoursworkedAS 'Hrs'
,’amt’ as ‘Table’
FROM Mastertabletesting 
WHERE HoursWorked IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY ID, Employer, month(WorkDate), year(WorkDate)

UNION all

SELECT ID AS 'ID'
,Employer AS 'Emp'
,month(CAST((RIGHT(workdate, 4) + LEFT(workdate, 4)) AS DATE)) AS 'Mnth'
,YEAR(CAST((RIGHT(workdate, 4) + LEFT(workdate, 4)) AS DATE)) AS 'Yr'
,hoursworked AS 'Hrs'
,‘alt’ as ‘Table’
FROM Loadtabletesting
WHERE HoursWorked IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY ID, Employer, month(CAST((RIGHT(workdate, 4) +LEFT workdate,4)) AS DATE)), year(CAST((RIGHT(workdate, 4) + LEFT(workdate, 4)) AS DATE))
```

Then I am using a common table expression to find those which have over 300 hours in a particular month and then using a query to join to the CTE in order to add the employer they worked for. Any suggestions on how to add a line under the hours column for each month for the total would be greatly appreciated.

```
   with monthsum as(
    Select ID as 'ID'
    , mnth as 'mnth'
    , yr as 'yr'
    ,SUM(hrs)as 'TotalHrs'
    From over300agtest
    Group by ID, mnth, yr
    having SUM(hrs) > 300)

Select ms.ID
,ms.mnth
,ms.yr
,emp
,hrs
,o3.[table]
,totalhrs
From monthsum ms left outer join over300agtest o3
on ms.ID = o3.ID and ms.mnth = o3.mnth and ms.yr =o3.yr
Order by ms.ID,  ms.yr asc, ms.mnth asc
```

Here is the current output:

```
+----+------+------+-------+-----+-------+----------+
| ID | mnth |  yr  |  emp  | hrs | table | totalhrs |
+----+------+------+-------+-----+-------+----------+
| 25 |    7 | 2016 |  7502 |  24 | AMT   |      484 |
| 25 |    7 | 2016 | 21874 | 128 | AMT   |      484 |
| 25 |    7 | 2016 |  7502 | 166 | AMT   |      484 |
| 25 |    7 | 2016 |  7500 | 166 | ALT   |      484 |
| 72 |    8 | 2016 |  7508 | 180 | AMT   |      563 |
| 72 |    8 | 2016 |  5501 | 180 | AMT   |      563 |
| 72 |    8 | 2016 | 21037 |  23 | AMT   |      563 |
| 72 |    8 | 2016 |  7500 | 180 | ALT   |      563 |
+----+------+------+-------+-----+-------+----------+
```

Here is the output I am going for:

```
+-------+------+------+-------+-----+-------+
|  ID   | mnth |  yr  |  emp  | hrs | table |
+-------+------+------+-------+-----+-------+
| 25    |    7 | 2016 |  7502 |  24 | AMT   |
| 25    |    7 | 2016 | 21874 | 128 | AMT   |
| 25    |    7 | 2016 |  7502 | 166 | AMT   |
| 25    |    7 | 2016 |  7500 | 166 | ALT   |
| Total |      |      |       | 484 |       |
| 72    |    8 | 2016 |  7508 | 180 | AMT   |
| 72    |    8 | 2016 |  5501 | 180 | AMT   |
| 72    |    8 | 2016 | 21037 |  23 | AMT   |
| 72    |    8 | 2016 |  7500 | 180 | ALT   |
| Total |      |      |       | 563 |       |
+-------+------+------+-------+-----+-------+
```

Comment: It would help if you can provide table schema for for `Load` and `Master` tables as well as sample data. What is more important is that it seems that you have `ID` in both tables that potentially can overlap when you push records into a single view.

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Comment: I'm not sure you can do what you're trying to do with plain SQL. You can get the hrs sums through partitioning, but I think you'll have to programmatically get the display output that you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest this approach.  You should be able to work out the specifics.

```
select convert(char(6), cast(workdate as date), 120) yearMonth
, sum(hrs) totalHours
from etc
group by convert(char(6), cast(workdate as date), 120) 
having sum(hrs) > 300
```

Comment: I'm using SQL Server 2008. Tried using the above code. Received the message: Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.